# Como enviar dois action em um único form?

Tags: javascript, html

Olá eu tenho um botão do pagseguro no meu site, porém quando eu clico nele eu quero que ele pegue os dados do formulário e envie para outra página (para depois coloca-lo no banco de dados). Assim quando clicar no botão do pagseguro ele enviará dois action. (um para o pagseguro e outro para o meu bd.

Formulário do pagseguro.

```
<!-- INICIO FORMULARIO BOTAO PAGSEGURO -->
<form action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/v2/cart.html?action=add" method="post" onsubmit="PagSeguroLightbox(this); return false;">
<!-- NÃO EDITE OS COMANDOS DAS LINHAS ABAIXO -->
<input type="hidden" name="itemCode" value="DF45A4323B3BA53224E48FBA638D48CE" />
<input type="image" src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/209x48-pagar-assina.gif" name="submit" alt="Pague com PagSeguro - é rápido, grátis e seguro!" /> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.lightbox.js"></script>
```

Formulário do site.

```
<form method="post" action="">
            <table class="tb">
                <tr><td>Nome: </td><td><input type="text" name="nome"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>E-mail: </td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Telefone: </td><td><input type="text" name="telefone"></td></tr>
            </table>
 </form>
```

Estou pensando em colocar os dois no mesmo form, porém a pergunta continua. Como enviar para duas páginas diferentes via action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Você apenas pode submeter uma vez o formulário para a url informada. Para solucionar o seu problema você pode enviar essas requisições via ajax.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800343/posting-mvc-razor-form-from-ajax

Exemplo :

```
<form>
Primeiro nome: 
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Último nome: 
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="button" value="Save" id="saveName">
</form>
```

Script Js :

```
$('#saveName').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json'
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<SUA URL>'
    }).done(function (data) {
       //Tratar algum retorno da sua aplicação
    });

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json'
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<URL PAGSEGURO>'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo padrao do W3C, uma vez que voce submete um formulario, voce ja navegou e nao pode mais submeter exatamente o mesmo formulario, por isso que voce define apenas um target na action. Um workaround pra o seu caso pode ser:

1. Primeiro voce envia os dados do seu formulario via Ajax pra gravar no seu banco
2. Depois pode submeter o formulario normalmente para o pagseguro, como voce esta' fazendo agora

Comment: Eu pensei a mesma coisa,  talvez seja a melhor maneira de fazer.  Preenche o formulário e depois vai para o pagseguro.

Comment: Com certeza é melhor mesmo, envia ajax e depois no success envia para o pagseguro